# How can I report a bug on Ubuntu.com?

Tags: bug-reporting, ubuntu-website

Today I wanted to download a copy of Ubuntu Server and when I went to the [Download Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) for Ubuntu Server there appeared to be a problem in the download button.

Instead of saying `Download` like the other button (below), it read: `LTS', 'eventValue' : undefined });">Download`, now this could be something minor such as a `SyntaxError` or a problem on the server.

So instead of downloading the OS and instead went to look for a "report bug" feature, but to my avail, I could not find one. Could someone please help me report this problem and bring attention to this issue? Maybe show me how to report it to the Ubuntu Developers?

I really wouldn't mind if someone reported the bug on my behalf just as long as it is fixed, that's all that matters at the moment, thanks.

Also here is a screen shot of the web page (time and date on the top bar):

[image: Screen Shot.]

---

## Update:

This problem has now been fixed, screenshot:

[image]

Thanks a tonne guys.

Comment: You can head to http://releases.ubuntu.com directly for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of https://www.ubuntu.com, there is a link titled "Report a bug on this site" which goes to https://github.com/ubuntudesign/www.ubuntu.com/issues/new